# Pros and Cons of Product Line Software Development

Tags: methodology, software-product-lines

Has anybody here implemented a software product line approach, as defined by the [SEI](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/productlines/)? How do you manage changes? How do you test? What problems have you had to deal with?

For years we've basically been trying to follow a product line approach, but I am constantly fighting Program Managers who don't want to pay for testing changes not strictly required for their program, and yet want free bug fixes. They also are very scared of changes happening to the code base that they don't need... not an unreasonable fear.

This has culminated in my getting an action item at our last PDR to explain the product line approach and why I think we should follow it. I've found [softwareproductlines.com](http://www.softwareproductlines.com/), which has a few success stories, but not enough details on how to counter the potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 3):

A [recent SE Radio podcast](http://www.se-radio.net/2009/10/episode-146-interesting-patterns-at-europlop-2009/) had a small section discussing product line development. I believe it was the very first section.

There are also three other SE Radio podcasts that might be of interest - [Episode 53: Product Line Engineering Pt. 1](http://www.se-radio.net/2007/04/episode-53-product-line-engineering-pt-1/), [Episode 58: Product Line Engineering Pt. 2](http://www.se-radio.net/2007/06/episode-58-product-line-engineering-pt-2/), and [Episode 90: Product Line Engineering Pt. 3](http://www.se-radio.net/2008/03/episode-90-product-line-engineering-pt-3-with-charles-krueger/).

I'm not sure how well these cover everything you need to know, but it will at least be a start. And perhaps you can get some pointers on where to go next from these podcasts.

Comment: I really should go through and summarize the key points from these podcasts to make this a good answer by today's standards. That's on my to-do, but it won't happen for a while, unfortunately.